# Unable to mount SD card at crouton startup

Tags: ubuntu, chroot, chrome-book

I am just starting out running Ubuntu trusty through crouton on my chromebook, and I am attempting at mounting my sd card at startup. I currently have a shell script which mounts the sd card when it is run, but I am not able to get my script to run at startup.

I have tried adding it to startup adding it to `/etc/init.d` and updating `rc`, I have attempted to add it to `rc.local`, I have tried adding it to `fstab`, and finally was a last ditch effort to add it to `startup applications`. I ended up just creating a shortcut that runs the program with root access, but I have to click it everytime I start up. Any help would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [systemd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd) or create a **bash** file with your commands, like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo MYAPPLICATION
```

And add in first line of your `~/.bashrc` file like this:

```
source ~/.MYAPPLICATION.sh
```